# Is there a word that refers to the phrase that follows a dialog?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word that refers to the phrase that follows a dialog? By that, I mean phrases such as "said Matthew", "exclaimed John", etc. Is there a word that refers to those phrases we use in novels?

For example:

> "That was sweet!" **said John.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [**dialogue tag**](https://thewritepractice.com/dialogue-tags/).

From the link:

> Also often referred to as an attribution, a dialogue tag is a small phrase either before, after, or in between the actual dialogue itself. For example:
>
> “Did you get my letter?” asked Katie.
>
> The phrase “asked Katie” is the dialogue tag in the sentence.

Note: other interesting comments and information may be found in the link.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for may be "speech tag."

Answer (score 0):

It's normally called either a **dialogue tag** or a **speech tag**.

From ["Dialogue tags and how to use them in fiction writing"](https://www.louiseharnbyproofreader.com/blog/dialogue-tags-and-how-to-use-them-in-fiction-writing) by Louise Harnby:

> Dialogue tags – or speech tags – are what writers use to indicate which character is speaking. Their function is, for the most part, mechanical. This article is about how to use them effectively.
>
> A dialogue tag can come before, between or after direct speech:
>   ​
>         Dave said, ‘That’s the last thing I expected you to say.’
>         ‘That,’ said Dave, ‘is the last thing I expected you to say.’
>         ‘That’s the last thing I expected you to say,’ Dave said.​
>
> Placed in between direct speech, tags can moderate the pace by forcing the reader to pause, and improve the rhythm by breaking up longer chunks.